# Why can't WPF datagrid sort when data implements IEditableObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In WPF, [DataGrids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) automatically support sorting -- the user can click on a column header it will be sorted.  Datagrid also automatically supports "transactional editing"
if the elements support the [IEditableObject interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx).  That is, you will be informed when the user starts editting a row, and also when she finishes (commits or cancels).

<del>But if I make my data implement `IEdtiableObject`, the column sorting stops working.  That is, the headers are no longer clickable unless I explicitly set the [CanUserSort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.canusersort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and even then, clicking on the column does nothing.</del>

So why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: The premise of the question turns out to be wrong.  The problem was not that for some reason sorting cared about the `IEditableObject` interface.  Instead I was storing those objects in a `BindingList`, and bindinglists don't support sorting.

Comment: Do you use auto-generated columns or you set them explicitly? In the second case, could you post column definitions?

Comment: The question turns out to be incorrect.  The problem is not that the data implement `IEditableObject`, it was actually that I was storing them in a `BindingList`, which is not sortable.